# changing the onblur attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the onblur attribute of a text field with jQuery

But it's not working

The input field already has some onblur code like this:

```
<input id="emp" type="text" onblur="func1('abc');">
```

Using jQuery I want to change it to this:

```
<input id="emp" type="text" onblur="func2('abc','def');">
```

I am trying this code:

```
$('#emp').attr('onblur',"func2('abc','def')")
```

But it does nothing ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors, you have to escape your quotes

```
$('#emp').attr('onblur','func2(\'abc\',\'def\')')
```

Comment: ahh .. sorry, I am already using the quotes as you said. But I made a mistake while typing here on stackoverflow. I am doing the same as you said, but it's not working for me. If it works for you, can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not quoting the attribute properly. You should try something like this:

```
$('#emp').attr('onblur',"func2('abc','def')")
```

Comment: ahh .. sorry, I am already using the quotes as you said. But I made a mistake while typing here on stackoverflow. I am doing the same as you said, but it's not working for me. If it works for you, can you please provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the inline onblur code completely and do it in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emp').on('blur',function() {
        func2('abc', 'def');
    });
});​
```

Comment: It has to be done after the document is ready. I have to do it in the success callback of an ajax request. That's the main problem :(